# Get html content from webView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I have the webView shows the content like the image. My purpose is that i want to print out exactly the string `Thanh toán thành công` and i don't want to get any html format. Please help me how to handle it. Appreciate your helping !

[image]

My code:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    print("pageDidFinished")
    if let html = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML") {
        print("html=[\(html)]")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
html=[
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Vnpay_return.aspx?vnp_Amount=1000000&amp;vnp_BankCode=NCB&amp;vnp_BankTranNo=20181129164553&amp;vnp_CardType=ATM&amp;vnp_OrderInfo=Thanh+toan+goi+kham+iCNM&amp;vnp_PayDate=20181129164626&amp;vnp_ResponseCode=00&amp;vnp_TmnCode=MLATEC02&amp;vnp_TransactionNo=13115440&amp;vnp_TxnRef=636791069787342509&amp;vnp_SecureHashType=MD5&amp;vnp_SecureHash=8e346e3b07cae8655972bec0e68f30e0" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTIxMzA2NDI4Ng9kFgICAw9kFgICAQ8WAh4JaW5uZXJodG1sBSRUaGFuaCB0byYjMjI1O24gdGgmIzIyNDtuaCBjJiMyNDQ7bmdkZCNmBqLZpz4DIdi6COyJTTG5SVGH">
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="C462C8FC">
</div>
     <div class="container">
            <div class="header clearfix">

                <h3 class="text-muted">Kết quả thanh toán</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                 <div id="displayMsg">Thanh toán thành công</div>
            </div> </div>
    </form>

  <script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

]
```

Comment: you can use your webview function stringByEvaluatingJavaScript to retrieve the required text.

Comment: i use this but it prints out a lot of stuff include the html code. I don't want it, i just want get exactly the string

Comment: maybe you can share your input html code

Comment: ok bro, i will edit it right now. Thank for your comment

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the inner text of the div by:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    guard let text = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById(\"displayMsg\").innerText") else {
        return
    }

    print(text) // Thanh toán thành công
}
```

Comment: perfect answer. You save my time. Thank you so much